# Move folders across projects in the same repository in Subversion

Tags: svn

I am trying to move folders across projects within the same repository. So I intend to use the svn move command or right click and drag the folder. Does this seem ok and wil it ensure that no revisions are lost? Also there are some svn properties on the folders so does move keep those properties intact?

I have tried right clig and drag and then select SVN Copy and add files to WC option which gives me this message "Could not copy files. Access is denied."

How can I fix this?

Comment: Considering that stock Subversion is command-line only, you might want to tell us what SVN GUI you're using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `svn mv URL URL` form of the svn move command, then you do not need to worry about local file permissions. So, assuming that your svn server is at http://svnserver/svn and you want to move the folder X from project1 to project2, then do the following:

```
svn mv http://svnserver/svn/trunk/project1/X http://svnserver/svn/trunk/project2/X
```

The previous command will prompt you for the checkin message, if you would prefer to enter it on the command line, then use the following form:

```
svn mv -m "checkin message" \
  http://svnserver/svn/trunk/project1/X http://svnserver/svn/trunk/project2/X
```

Comment: Added benefit of the URL form: Subversion only has to copy the directory information.  It doesn't see the copy as a set of new files with no prior history.

Comment: Don't forget to specify a log message!

Comment: I updated the answer to also include the form with the message on the command line.